# Convert an array of UIImages into base64 string

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiimage, base64

I have an array of multiple images (`UIImage`) in:

```
NSMutableArray *myImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:attachment];
```

and I want to pass it to API server as a `base64` `string` with commas. Such as, (`Base64String`,`Image1`), (`Base64String`,`Image2`) etc.

**Note:** This is how I used to do it for a single image which is not an array.

```
(NSData *)attachment //get as a parameter

NSData *base64Data = [attachment base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:base64Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64Image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", str, @"image1"];

parameters[@"Attachment"] = base64Image; //pass to API as parameter
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. It is basically converting each image to Base 64 and push into one big String.

Comment: The changes I made are functionally the same as what you had, they're just a cleaner syntax.  `parameters[@"Attachment"] = base64Image;` gets turned by the compiler into `[parameters setObject:base64Image forKeyedSubscript:@"Attachment"];`, and `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` is an alias for `setObject:forKey:`.  I highly recommend you use the cleaner syntax in day-to-day use; it'll save both your fingers and eyes from unnecessary strain.

Comment: See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#object-subscripting and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/setObject:forKeyedSubscript: for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you already have everything you need. Just create a mutable string and append each base64 encoded image using a for loop, something along the following lines (typed quickly and not tested):

```
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString new];
for (int i = 0; i < myImages.count; i++) {
    NSData *base64Data = [myImages[i] base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];
    NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:base64Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64Image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@,%@%d),", str, @"image", i+1];
    [result appendFormat:@"%@", base64Image];
}
```

You can then trim away the final comma and you have the string you need.

Comment: will give u crash if myImages is empty

Comment: if you change 3rd line as NSData *base64Data = [UIImagePNGRepresentation([myImages objectAtIndex:i]) base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0]; it will work.

Comment: @vaibby: No it won't.  It'll just leave `result` as a zero-length mutable string and not run the loop a single time.  It would crash if `myImages` is `nil` (as opposed to “empty”).

Comment: @vaibby i just have tried and it works perfect. you can try when you have free time.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson No, it won't crash if `myImages` is `nil`. Why would it? `myImages.count` would simply return `0` if `myImages` is `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy `[myImages count]` would return `0` which would work but is considered hacky-C-style code nowadays, and is not recommended.  `myImages.count` would indeed crash.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Sorry but no. `myImages.count` is the same thing as `[myImages count]`. Neither will crash if `myImages` is `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy Okay, just tried it.  You're right— `myImages.count` also returns `0` if you're using a `NSArray *myImages`.  They're not exactly the same in all cases, however.  The difference that I was forgetting was that if you instead had an `id myImages` then `[myImages count]` would work as expected, while `myImage.count` results in a compile-time _`error: property 'count' not found on object of type 'id'`_.  Dot-syntax is more strict about type-checking, and bracket syntax is more loose.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *myImagesData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if (myImages.count != 0){
    for (int i = 0; i <= myImages.count-1; i++) {
        UIImage *img = myImages[i];
        NSData *base64Data = [img base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:base64Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [myImagesData addObject:str];
    }
}
//you will get all images data in array
```

Comment: Thank you but you are only putting array of images into another array. This is what i have.

Comment: when i put self attachment, i get this error: "no visible interface declares the selector attachment". Because, attachment is a parameter being passed from other class, its not my property.

Comment: Sorry i dont get you :/

Comment: There is no need for the `if` statement before the loop if the loop is fixed to be: `for (NSInteger i = 0; i < myImages.count; i++) {`.